# Oracle sql developer is getting stuck when the print button in pressed

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with my oracle sql develover. Everytime when I press by mistake on the print button the oracle is getting stuck and I need to close it by task manager and open it again.
If someone can help me it will be grate.
Thank you!

I have tried to change the version but is not working anyway.

Comment: Which SQL Developer version is it? Do you have any installed printers? If not, try to install *any printer*, just to fool SQL Developer.

Comment: the next time it hangs, use the jdk bin jstack uitlity to get a stacktrace, we can then see what's causing Java's printDialog to getting locked

Comment: I use sqldeveloper-21.4.1.349.1822-x64 version. 
No, I don't have any printer installed.

Comment: How I can use the jdk bin jstack uitlity to get a stacktrace?